# Creating and populating row in a table for missing dates after each first valid entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a dataset that represents number of views on individual files per day.

I would like to import this data into some visualization tool and show how many views a file received each day, beginning with the first valid date with an entry, in the form of something like a bar graph.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Metadata1 | Metadata2 | Unique_Item_ID |    Item_ID     | Unique Views | Total View Count |   Start_Date    |     End_Date     |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Folder1   | Subf1     | {000dda83}     | Document.docx  |            6 |               11 | 11/27/2019 0:00 | 11/27/2019 23:59 |
| Folder2   | Sub2f     | {004120b6}     | Reporting.mp4  |            3 |               10 | 11/8/2019 0:00  | 11/8/2019 23:59  |
| Folder2   | Sub2f     | {004120b6}     | Reporting.mp4  |            8 |               13 | 11/20/2019 0:00 | 11/20/2019 23:59 |
| Folder2   | Sub2f     | {004120b6}     | Reporting.mp4  |           12 |               27 | 11/29/2019 0:00 | 11/29/2019 23:59 |
| Folder3   | Sub3f     | {004f9957}     | Case Study.pdf |            1 |                1 | 10/8/2019 0:00  | 10/8/2019 23:59  |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+----------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

From a query like:

```
SELECT
   TOP 5 [Metadata1],
   [Metadata2],
   [Unique_Item_ID],
   [Item_ID],
   [Unique Views],
   [Total View Count],
   [Start_Date],
   [End_Date]
FROM
   DailyViewStats
```

How can I create a view that will create and populate rows with 0 view count for each Unique_Item_ID that does not exist, but only after the first occurrence of a valid existing row for each distinct Unique_Item_ID?

I know that I can use a partition function to identify the first valid row for each Unique_Item_ID, but I'm not sure how to leverage this. I tried using a cross join on all distinct Start_Dates in the table, to match up with all the unique items and their metadata, but I was unable to determine a WHERE statement that effectively removed any entry before the first valid one per Unique_Item_ID.

Using

```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Unique_Item_ID ORDER BY Start_Date ASC) as RowNum
```

I believe I can use this to identify the minimum dates I need when RowNum = 1. But how do I use this?

If today were 11/29, for Document.docx, I want to see something like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Metadata1 | Metadata2 | Unique_Item_ID |    Item_ID    | Unique Views | Total View Count |   Start_Date    |     End_Date     |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Folder1   | Subf1     | {000dda83}     | Document.docx |            6 |               11 | 11/27/2019 0:00 | 11/27/2019 23:59 |
| Folder1   | Subf1     | {000dda83}     | Document.docx |            0 |                0 | 11/28/2019 0:00 | 11/28/2019 23:59 |
| Folder1   | Subf1     | {000dda83}     | Document.docx |            0 |                0 | 11/29/2019 0:00 | 11/29/2019 23:59 |
+-----------+-----------+----------------+---------------+--------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

For each file existing in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One direct way to do this is to employ a calendar table. In the example below the calendar is provided by a recursive CTE with a ~37K range of days. Once that is set up you want to overlay each of the unique Id's with each day. This is done below in the form of a cross join CTE, only including the keys. From the derived cross join table, simply LEFT JOIN the bulk of your data and the values will appear aligned with each day of the calendar. I took the liberty of simplifying your model below.

```
 DECLARE @T TABLE( Unique_Item_ID NVARCHAR(50), Total_View_Count INT, DateViewed DATETIME)

 INSERT @T VALUES
 ('000dda83',11, '11/27/2019'),
 ('004120b6',10, '11/8/2019'),
 ('004120b6',13, '11/20/2019')

DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '10/01/2019' 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '01/01/2020' 

;WITH OrderedDays as 
( 
    SELECT CalendarDate = @StartDate
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT CalendarDate = DATEADD(DAY, 1, CalendarDate)
    FROM OrderedDays WHERE DATEADD (DAY, 1, CalendarDate) <= @EndDate 
),
Calendar AS
(
    SELECT
        DayIndex = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY CalendarDate),
        CalendarDate,
        CalenderDayOfMonth = DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderMonthOfYear = DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate),
        CalendarYear = DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekOfYear = DATEPART(WEEK, CalendarDate),
        CalenderQuarterOfYear = DATEPART(QUARTER, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfYear =  DATEPART(DAYOFYEAR, CalendarDate),
        CalenderDayOfWeek =  DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate),
        CalenderWeekday =  DATENAME(WEEKDAY, CalendarDate)   
    FROM
        OrderedDays                 
)
,CrossJoinData AS
(
    SELECT Unique_Item_ID, CalendarDate
    FROM
        Calendar C
        CROSS JOIN @T T
    GROUP BY 
        Unique_Item_ID, CalendarDate
    HAVING
        MIN(T.DateViewed) <= C.CalendarDate

)
SELECT 
    CJ.Unique_Item_ID,
    CJ.CalendarDate,
    T.Total_View_Count
FROM
    CrossJoinData CJ
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @T T ON T.Unique_Item_ID = CJ.Unique_Item_ID AND T.DateViewed = CJ.CalendarDate
ORDER BY
    CJ.Unique_Item_ID,
    CJ.CalendarDate

OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I realized that I missed the point where you wanted the values to appear only after the first view, that can be done above in the cross join by using the MIN(DateViewed) aggregate against each rows date in a HAVING clause.

Comment: Ross, that was very helpful. I didn't think to use a having clause in my cross join which seems to do the trick. I guess in that case the rownumber is unnecessary.